# useState state update in callback referencing old state

Tags: reactjs

```js
const Child1 = (props) => {
  
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({count: 1, enabled: true})
  
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    setObj({...obj, count: obj.count+1})
  }
  
  const onDelayedIncrement = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setObj({...obj, count: obj.count+1})
    }, 3000) 
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{obj.count}</div>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Increment</button>
      <div><button onClick={onDelayedIncrement}>Delayed Increment</button></div>
    </div>
  );
};



ReactDOM.render(
  <Child1 />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

In the above code if we click `Delayed increment` and later if we keep on clicking `Increment`, after setTimeout is executed and when setState is called it is using old state. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the functional form of `setState`:

```
setObj(currentObj => ({...currentObj, count: currentObj.count+1}))
```

More info in the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

[Hooks related documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here is the exact link for documentation - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it to the answer.